# Dedicated database/web account for Jenkins-to-Sonar integration

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, sonarqube

I would like to create a dedicated account for Jenkins-to-Sonar JDBC connection and web login.

Most HOWTO's I found use the Sonar admin account, the [official documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin) for the Jenkins/Sonar plugin even uses the postgresql account. Specifically, I'm looking for the privileges I should grant to the jenkins user (and on what tables, etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a user.

```
CREATE USER jenkins_sonar WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'whatever';
```

Then `GRANT` that user rights to access the sonar tables in the database you're using for sonar. See [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html), in particular `GRANT ... ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...`. You may also want to `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` so the jenkins user gets the same rights on new tables. If sequences are used you'll need to `GRANT` access to them too. Finally, you may need to `GRANT` usage of the schema the data is in, if it isn't in `public`.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for your reply. If I'n not mistaking, your instructions will create a generic account database account. But I'm looking for the _specific priviliges_ I should grant to Jenkins (maybe I should rephrase/clarify my question?).

Comment: @Willem I sincerely doubt that'll be documented anywhere useful - you'll probably need to look at the Jenkins plugin sources to see what SQL it executes and run appropriate GRANTs. Or capture the SQL it runs using a generic account from the PostgreSQL logs and use that to decide what rights to grant. A third option is just to do a grant, run, observe error, grant cycle, where you grant required rights until it stops dying.

Comment: Hi @Craig, thanks for the update. I think I'll go with capture-the-sql.